# This is the best day in/of my life

Tags: grammar, difference

I wonder if there is a steadfast rule for when to use *in* and when to use *of* with superlative forms:

> I'm so happy. This is the best day of my life.
>
> This is the worst depression in US history.
>
> The best coffee house in the country.

[English Usage has the same question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149422/in-vs-of-after-the-superlative-form-of-adjectives), but people seem to differ and answers are probably subjective.

Answer (score 1):

`Of` is used where it indicates an element of a set, whereas `in` might be used more often where the set is less clear, or is treated as a continuum... but this doesn't seem to be a "hard and fast" rule.

Set of all Aroma cafes:

> The Aroma coffee shop in Lod is the best of them all.

Continuum of the whole country:

> The Aroma coffee shop in Lod is the best in the country.

And yet, in the following two sentences, the prepositions seem interchangeable.

> 1947 was the best year of the last century in India.
>
> 1947 was the best year in the last century in India.

If there is any small, subtle difference in connotation, it *might* be that `of` draws attention to the year being in a particular century, and `in` includes both country and time, more of a continuum... and perhaps I'm looking for a difference that is not there. sigh